# Failed install ubuntu on Lenovo Ideapad Slim 5

Tags: boot, nvidia, lenovo

Lenovo IP Slim 5 14ITL05 i7-1165G7

Laptop Spec:

- Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 (12M Cache, up to 4.70 GHz, with IPU)
- 16GB DDR4
- 512GB SSD M.2 2242 PCIe NVMe 3.0x2
- NVIDIA GeForce MX450 (2GB)
- Default OS Windows 10 + Office Home and Student 2019

I want to install Ubuntu on my new laptop,I use USB drive with ubuntu 20.04 lts
and then i choose Erase Disk and Install.

After installation i got this :
[image]

And then after i remove USB and restart PC i got this:
[image]

Comment: It needs at least 21.04 (21.10 will be better and 22.04 even better) due to the brand new hardware. Make sure to select the option to install 3rd party driver which includes Nvidia drivers. Of course, disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: so I can't use Ubuntu 20.04? why? and also why i need to disabled secure Boot in UEFI ? do you mean disabled in BIOS Mode ?

Comment: You *may* try using a release almost 2 years older than the hardware when said release has a kernel version with proper support for the hardware, 20.04 isn't there yet. You need to either disable Secure Boot in **UEFI** (you have UEFI, not BIOS. UEFI *replaced* BIOS a decade ago, give or take) - easy way - or use mokutil to sign the Nvidia drivers - not recommended for someone that doesn't know basic stuff yet -.

Comment: so if i disabled secure boot it will work on Ubuntu 20.04 ? or still i need to install 21.04 ?

Comment: what is the drawback of disabling secure boot ?

Comment: Absolutely no drawback unless you intend to install Windows 11 at some point (Windows 11 very likely will require Secure Boot enabled unlike Windows 10).

Comment: so I still need to install ubuntu 21.04? what if I disabled secure boot and install ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Honestly, what you should do is learn first, try later. This question follow the same path of your previous questions and has the same problems commented before. This is a Q&A, not a forum, not a chat. Comments are meant to clarification (or in this case to provide trivial information not worth an answer). Comments AREN'T meant for discussion and I certainly won't engage in *whatifism* considering that everything that is to know about the problem has been commented already.